# Strange CSS issue with my headline

Tags: css, background-image

For some reason the background for the headline of my post is getting cut off when the title goes onto a second line.  Check out:

http://www.widehiverecords.com/calvin-keys-in-featured-in-american-rag/

And compare it to:
http://www.widehiverecords.com/perseverance-phil-ranelin-with-henry-franklin-and-big-black/

I've looked at every element and I'm not sure what the problem is.  I figured out that if I turn the line height down to 1em for the title, the problem goes away, but that doesn't explain what is causing it.

I'd appreciate any help!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I can see what you're talking about. Can you take some screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The div is getting wide enough that the background is repeating. Just change the rule for `.custom .top .headline_area h1, .custom .top .headline_area h2, .custom #archive_intro h1` from

`background: url(/wp/images/h1_wood.png)`

to

`background: url(/wp/images/h1_wood.png) no-repeat`

### edit

In case this question is stumbled onto in the future after the link has been fixed, here's what it looks like now, with the red circles highlighting the area.
[image: Problem]

Comment: Thank you Robert!  OBVIOUS.  Ha!  :)